# Como chamar action do controlador?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, helper

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
function confirmaExclusao() {
    var decisao = confirm("Deseja excluir permanentemente esse item?");
    if(decisao == true)
    {
        //Chamar a action para excluir
    }
    else
    {
        //Aqui não vai fazer nada!
    }
}
```

Preciso chamar uma `ActionResult` de um `Controller` em C# enviando um argumento, como posso fazer isso?

Como se fosse um `RedirectToAction`.

Comment: Com o `RedirectToAction` não dá certo? algo como `return RedirectToAction("TuaAcao", new { argumento = valor });`.

Comment: Não tenho conseguido usar o RedirectToAction na View, nem mesmo aparece no auto complete.

Comment: `RedirectToAction` é um método da classe `ApiController` - logo, não está disponível na view. Além disso, mesmo que estivesse disponível, seria inútil. O método retorna uma instancia de `RedirectToRouteResult`, que não tem significado nenhum no contexto de Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode chamar a action da seguinte maneira.

```
$.ajax
({ 
    url: '/controller/action',
    type: 'GET', (ou method que precisa)
    success: function (dados) {
        var resultado = dados; // Caso vá retornar alguma coisa
    },
    error: function (erro) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Gostaria de uma alternativa em Razor...

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Nao ha alternativa, precisas de fazer um pedido por Ajax. A unica coisa que podes melhorar no codigo e' usar `@Url.RouteUrl("RouteName")` (se usares attribute-based routing) ou `@Url.Action("ActionName")` em vez de escrever a URL manualmente `'/controller/action'`.